# Drawing 3 marbles of a bag with 4 marbles

Tags: probability, permutations

In my practice exam I have the following question and the answer is supposedly $\frac{2}{3}$, but I don't get why.

```
A bag contains two red and two green marbles. Three marbles are drawn,
one after the other and without replacement, what is the probability that the
drawn marbles are different colors?
```

Isn't it that I will always draw $2$ marbles of one color and $1$ marble of the other color, so the probability to draw marbles with different colors is always $100$%?

Comment: I agree with your reasoning and your conclusion.  I expect there is a typo.  Note that $\frac 23$ would be correct if you drew *two* marbles instead of *three*.

Comment: Oh yeah, that could be. Thank you @lulu